# MTAThread attribute and winform app with multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, attributes, entry-point

I've done some reading on this at MSDN and around the web and now more confused than before.

I am working with a vb.net windows form application and wish to use multiple threads (but not multiple apartments).

Does this mean I need to set MTAThread attribute on the program entry point or not?

Some sources seem to indicate yes, some say a windows form app should be STA because of the COM objects, some say MTA will be set automatically when threads are created, some not... thoroughly confused now.

If I do need to set it can I do this without disabling the app framework and creating amodule to hold a `Public Sub Main()`?

Comment: Could you also explain what your trying to accomplish? Maybe we have a diff approach for you.

Comment: @DonA My first threaded app, still not sure if I even need to set <MTAThread>, no source is clear enough on when it should or should not be set. App is single apartment, multiple simple threads, windows forms app. Form UI on the default foreground thread, everything else on various background threads. Some of the BG threads will need to interact with each other and the UI. Is that enough info?

Comment: What kind of work are they doing? How are they supposed to comm with each other?

Comment: One will run a TcpListner, another of them is working as a scheduler that basically decides when to do a task (taskA), uses a context object related to JobA to spawn a new thread to actually do TaskA for JobA which will then spawn other threads for doing things like talking to SQL db, TCP clients, etc. I'm still working out how they'll talk to each other as Im still learning threading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider puttin the `TCPListener` in a class object, with properties that the calling form can access, this class can have events your form can listen for and pass data to the UI - `delegates` maybe needed. The tasks could be class objects too and there can be a `List(Of Task)` Since they are class objects too they can now raise events which will be heard by it's owner that is listening for them. Any task that is being handled on a seperate thread will require delegates even with event raising.